# How to use message_tag's java script enum when posting by using Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, enums

Im developing Facebook posting app by using graph API in javascript. My problem is how to use message_tag's type?

API says use this enum to provide type of the message_tag, `enum{user, page, group}` but I have't any idea how to use this enum.

This is my code,

```
var mTags = {id:"874868725965718", name:"Tag", type:user, offset:5, length:4};

FB.api('/' + fbUserId + '/feed', 'post',
                    {
                        message: 'Test Message',
                        link: 'http://iotonic.com.91-250-116-3.mbftest.ch/',
                        picture: 'http://iotonic.com.91-250-116-3.mbftest.ch/img/footerLogo.png',
                        name: 'Test Post',
                        description: "This is test description",
                        message_tags: mTags
                    },
            function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured' + token);
                    console.log(response.error);
                } else {
                    alert('Post added ' + token);
                }
            }
            );
```

Please give me some advice to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `message_tags` is a field you get back when _reading_ a post, you can not use it when _making_ a post. What fields are available for publishing, is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

Comment: Thank you very much @CBroe it works. Is there any way to find correct user id or page id in facebook?